# Why do I keep getting this NullReferenceException error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My script...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CountDownTimer : MonoBehaviour {

    public int score;
    float timeRemaining = 15;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
        score = GetComponent<TriggerZone>().score;
    }

    void OnGUI(){
        if (timeRemaining > 0) {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 100), "Time Remaining: "+(int)timeRemaining);
        }
        else{
            GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 100), "Times up your score was: " + score + ". Press the r button to restart, or ESC to quit.");
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
                Application.LoadLevel("Testing Grounds");
            if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
                Application.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object CountDownTimer.Update () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/CountDownTimer.cs:16)

I can't think of what could be causing this error. As I understand it's trying to tell me that something doesn't exist, but I can't think of what that might be. "score = GetComponent().score;" is accessing another script that contains the score value so that when the timer runs out it tells the player their score, and gives them the option to either quit, or restart the game.

Also if it helps here is the other script...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

public class TriggerZone : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Text MyText;
public int score;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    MyText.text = "";

}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    MyText.text = "$" + score;

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll) {

    if (coll.gameObject.HasTag ("ValueLevel1"))
        score = score + 5;

    if (coll.gameObject.HasTag ("ValueLevel2"))
        score = score + 25;

    if (coll.gameObject.HasTag ("ValueLevel3"))
        score = score + 50;

    if (coll.gameObject.HasTag ("ValueLevel4"))
        score = score + 100;

    if (coll.CompareTag ("Pickable")) {
        coll.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It sounds like `GetComponent<TriggerZone>()` is returning `null`, but we can't be sure because you haven't posted enough code for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: What else do you need? The other script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel stupid, but thanks to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/3h7tp4/why_do_i_keep_getting_this_nullreferenceexception/cu575hd) I finally found the issue. Turns out that I had my script attached to my FPS controller which was causing the null issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetComponent<TriggerZone>()
```

seems to be returning `null` and you are trying to access `.score` off of `null`. Your solutions are either to check the return for `null` and take appropriate actions or make sure that the call never returns `null`.

Comment: That's where I'm sort of lost. I use "score = GetComponent<TriggerZone>().score;" to grab the score value from TriggerZone. Without that it doesn't work. So it can't be returning null. I am relatively new to C# so sorry if I'm not making sense.

Comment: Check if both scripts (i.e. TriggerZone & CountDownTimer) are attached to the same GameObject. According to your script, they have to be. If you need them to be on seperate game objects, then change the GetComponent line to read something like score = REFERENCE_TO_OTHER_GO.GetComponent<TriggerZone>().score;

Comment: They are both attached to the same GameObject (as you said they must be). I have no idea why this isn't working as the game seems to run fine. I am sort of tempted to just move onto development, but I'd rather squash this bug first.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reasons, you might have missed the TriggerZone script/component for your CountDownTimer instance, try below attributes:

```
[RequireComponent (typeof (TriggerZone))]   //Try add this
public class CountDownTimer : MonoBehaviour {
...
}
```

This RequireComponent attribute lets you automatically add required component as a dependency. Below is from Unity3D official doc:

> When you add a script which uses RequireComponent, the required component will automatically be added to the game object. This is useful to avoid setup errors. For example a script might require that a rigid body is always added to the same game object. Using RequireComponent this will be done automatically, thus you can never get the setup wrong.

BTW: the below calls should not be called in Update(), preferably in Start() or Awake():

```
score = GetComponent<TriggerZone>().score;
```

Comment: Same thing even with the RequireComponent thing added in. The error just moved to Line 12 (in Start()). "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object CountDownTimer.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/CountDownTimer.cs:12)"

Comment: which line is 12? Can you add a comment to show the line 12 in your post?

Comment: Two things: I I tried moving the "score = GetComponent<TriggerZone>().score;" to Start(), and that broke it. The other thing is that no matter where I move "score = GetComponent<TriggerZone>().score;" to I always get the "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object CountDownTimer.OnGUI () (at Assets/Scripts/CountDownTimer.cs:25)" error. I made sure that the script (both of them) are attached to the proper game object. I am at my wits end here. [Here](http://pastebin.com/kD9Nz41t) is the code in it's current state.